# Change response for a blueprint action (Sails.JS)

Tags: sails.js

I have a `User` model with three attributes: `name`, `email` and `password`
I have a blueprint for this model, which means that actions are created for `find`, `findOne`, `create`, `...`

My problem is that `POST`ing some values on `/api/users` creates the user, but the password is included in response. Is there any way/hack to alter the response before sending it to the browser or should I rewrite the `create` action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the toJSON method

```
// api/models/User.js
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    username: 'string',
    password: 'string',

    // Override the default toJSON method

    toJSON: function() {
      var obj = this.toObject();
      delete obj.password;
      return obj;
    }
  }
}
```

http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/reference/waterline/records/toJSON.html

### Update

You can put the property `protected: true` on the `password` attribute and it does the same thing:

```
// api/models/User.js
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    username: 'string',
    password: { type: 'string', protected: true }
  }
}
```

http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/ORM/Validations.html